# FlinkKafkaConsumer not consuming from remote Kafka server

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I am trying to run a Flink job from a cluster. My Kafka producer is running on a remote machine. Below is my consumer's code:

```
val properties = new Properties()
properties.setProperty("bootstrap.servers", "172.xx.xx.xxx:9092")
properties.setProperty("group.id", "test")

val env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment
val stream = env.addSource(new FlinkKafkaConsumer011[String]("test", new SimpleStringSchema(), properties))
```

When I run the same program on the machine where kafka is running and replacing the IP address with `localhost:9092`, it runs fine. I am also able to ping the IP address from the machine where my Flink `JobManager` is running. But when I run the program on the cluster, there is no messages sent or received.

[image]

After a while, the job fails with exception:

```
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Timeout expired while fetching topic metadata
```

I am not able to figure out how to connect FlinkKafkaConsumer to my remote Kafka producer.

Comment: No need to connect the consumer to the producer. The adress you put into bootstrap.servers has to be a kafka broker adress. According to the port you gave that looks right but I just wanted to point this out.

Comment: @TobiSH By Kafka broker address you mean the address where Kafka and Zookeeper are running, right? The address is correct but the consumer is not getting any messages.

Comment: Which kafka version do you use? 0.11.x?

Comment: @TobiSH I am using Kafka 1.1.0

Comment: @PiyushShrivastava Hey! did you manage to solve this?. I'm facing the same issue.